# Comparing a given value against a multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I really need your help.

I'd like to structure and build an array like the below.:

```
var provinces = [
    ['Ontario','ON'],
    ['Quebec','QC'],
    ['British Columbia','BC'],
    ['Saskatchewan','SK']
];
```

then, id like to compare the value (x) against my array, ie:

```
var x = 'Ontario'

if (x matches the value in the array list 'provinces') { then let x = ON }
```

How do you write something like this in javascript?

Much thanks and appreciation for all your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.filter()` function, that receives a true/false return condition to retrieve itens from an array:

```js
var provinces = [
    ['Ontario','ON'],
    ['Quebec','QC'],
    ['British Columbia','BC'],
    ['Saskatchewan','SK']
];

var x = "Ontario";

//Find if any array item matches the word
var result = provinces.filter(function(item) {
  return item[0] == x;
});

//If there's a match, get the second index from the first result from the filter
if(result.length > 0)
  x = result[0][1];

alert(x);
```